# Constructing multigraph from vertex list

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given a list of vertices, with each vertex containing an edge list:

```
vertices = {{"foo","3","bar"},{"3","bar"},{"foo"}}
```

How can I construct a multigraph where each unique string in the input is an edge, connecting the two vertices containing that edge? The following almost works, but restricts the graph to single edges:

```
RelationGraph[(ContainsAny[#1,#2] && #1!=#2)&, vertices]
```

The actual names of the edges in the output isn't important, just the topology of the graph.

Comment: I looked at what your code generates and am confused.  If you add VertexLabels->"Name" to your code, you can see what I mean.  RelationGraph[(ContainsAny[#1, #2] && #1 != #2) &, vertices, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]  It is just as likely that I don't know what you are using for "vertices".  It isn't the first code line, is it?  It would help if you provided all inputs and your  partially working code.

Comment: @MarkR That is the only line of code, aside from setting `vertices` to a list like the one above. The vertex `{"foo","3","bar"}` is connected to `{"foo"}` by the "foo" edge. It should also be connected to `{"3","bar"}` by the "3" and "bar" edges, but there is only one edge in the result. (The actual names of the edges in the output isn't important.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct an adjacency matrix using [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) with `Length @* Intersection` as the first argument and use it with [`AdjacencyGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AdjacencyGraph.html):

```
am = Outer[Length @* Intersection, vertices, vertices, 1];
AdjacencyGraph[vertices, am - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[am]],
 DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, construct edge list using `Outer` and use `Graph`:

```
edgelist = Flatten[Outer[If[SameQ[##], {}, 
      ConstantArray[DirectedEdge[##], Length[Intersection[##]]]] &, 
    vertices, vertices, 1]]; 
Graph[edgelist, VertexLabels -> "Name",  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

> same picture

Comment: Nice solution.  If you want single (undirected) edges, how would you accomplish this?

Comment: @MarkR, remove DirectedEdges ->True in the first approach, for the second approach can't think of a way otomh.

Comment: thanks for letting me know.  Removing "DirectedEdges->True is a nice change.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following will do what you want.

```
verticeEdgeDescription = {{"foo", "3", "bar"}, {"3", 
"bar"}, {"foo"}};
(*give numbers to the vertices*)
vertexNumberPlusConnections = MapIndexed[{Last@#2, #1} &,verticeEdgeDescription];
combinations = Select[Tuples[vertexNumberPlusConnections, 2], #[[1]] != #[[2]] &];
combinations2 = DeleteDuplicates[Sort[#] & /@ combinations];
combinations3 = Select[{#[[1, 1]], #[[2, 1]], Intersection @@ #[[;; , -1]]} & /@ combinations2, #[[-1]] != {} &];
Graph[Flatten[With[{firstNode = #[[1]], secondNode = #[[2]], edges = #[[3]]}, 
 Labeled[firstNode \[UndirectedEdge] secondNode, #] & /@ 
  edges] & /@ combinations3], VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "Name"]
```

This is mostly doing what you want.  The one odd thing is that the labels in the generated graph seem wrong for the edges.

I'm not (yet) happy with how I determine the connections - too much manipulation to get unique connections.

[image: Generated Graph]

Here is the connection edges: 
{Labeled[1 [UndirectedEdge] 2, "3"] , 
 Labeled[1 [UndirectedEdge] 2, "bar"] , 
 Labeled[1 [UndirectedEdge] 3, "foo"]}